# Test ArrayAdapter in Android

Tags: android, android-testing

I'm trying to test my custom arrayAdapter and I'm having issues getting any list to appear

```
public class PlanOfCareCheckBoxAdapterTest extends AndroidTestCase
{
PlanOfCareCheckBoxAdapter mAdapter;
List<String> values;
Context mContext;

public PlanOfCareCheckBoxAdapterTest() {
    super();
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();

    mContext = new MockContext();
    new POCValues(mContext);

    values = Arrays.asList("One", "two", "three");
    mAdapter = new PlanOfCareCheckBoxAdapter(mContext, R.layout.item_multi_check, values, POCValues.masterMap);
    assertEquals("Two", mAdapter.getItem(0));
}
```

My implementation:

```
public class PlanOfCareCheckBoxAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
private BiMap<Integer, String> map;
private Set<Integer> mPendingItems, mDoneItems;
private boolean isSuperUser;

public PlanOfCareCheckBoxAdapter(Context context, int resource, List objects, BiMap<Integer, String> mapping) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    isSuperUser = false;
    mPendingItems = new HashSet<>();
    mDoneItems = new HashSet<>();
    map = mapping;
}
```

When I run this test I get an Actual result of null? why?